# How to adjust the padding of input using react native elements

Tags: react-native, styling, react-native-elements

I want to know how to adjust the padding in the InputContainer, and cutting out the space between the underline and the text.

To be precise, I want to adjust the size of padding(blue area) to 0 in InputContainer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBCsc.png

I have tried many possible styling props, but they didn't work. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Question Demo</Text>
      <Input 
        leftIcon={<Text>/</Text>}
        inputContainerStyle={{
          paddingHorizontal: 0,
          paddingVertical: 0,
        }}
        inputStyle={{
          paddingHorizontal: 0,
          paddingVertical: 0, 
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Instead of `paddingHorizontal` and `paddingVertical`, have you tried just `padding: 0`?

Comment: Or try `style={{ padding: 0 }}` instead of the `inputContainerStyle` and the `inputStyle`

Comment: brother you have to do it by digging deeper into node_modules.but it will undo the changes once you will yarn install again.you have to fork react-native-elements and then make changes in Input/index.js/ near borderBottomWidth:1, give some padding to 0 or play around and commit it to the forked library and use this forked lib in your packge.json by yarn install lib_url and then you can achieve this

Comment: @Zoha Malik, I try both of the answers, but neither of them works, thanks for your answers

Comment: @Zaid Qureshi, Thanks. I get it, so basically I cannot pass props to modify the padding there

Answer (score 1):

The container for the error message is the culprit for this issue. You can update **errorStyle** to get rid of this bottom padding issue.

```
const FormInput = (props: InputProps) => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  return (
    <Input
      errorStyle={{
        height: errorMessage ? 'auto' : 0,
        margin: errorMessage ? 2 : 0
      }}
    />
  );
};
```